# is there some characters that has the same encoding regardless which character set is used ? and if yes which are they?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, character-set

just asking if there is some characters that has the same encoding in all character sets and what are those characters exactly if there is a list of them ?
for example they may be the 0-9 characters or may be all English characters ... don't know !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no characters that have the same encoding in UTF-16 and ASCII (since UTF-16 is always a 2-byte encoding, and ASCII is always a 1-byte encoding). So the answer is no. (And of course I can invent a new encoding any time I like, so I can always make the answer be no. And EBCDIC has no overlap with ASCII except for a few control characters.)

If you are asking if there are characters that are the same in commonly used 1-byte encodings, except for EBCDIC, then almost all of the ASCII range (0-127) is identical in almost all common 1-byte encodings (as well as in UTF-8). The majority of 1-byte encodings are "extended ASCII" and, with a small number of exceptions, encode 0-127 the same. So, for a carefully selected meaning of "all encodings" (which is not even close to all encodings) the digits 0-9, the Latin alphabet, and some punctuation have the the same encoding. Certain control characters are the same for a slightly broader set of encodings (but I assume you're not looking for unprintables).

[But](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II_character_set#Apple_IIe) [in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amstrad_CPC_character_set) [general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX80_character_set), absolutely not.